# Troubleshooting a dead-ish ssd

Tags: ssd, data-recovery, partition-recovery

I have a dead-ish SSD drive. BIOS can't read it, Linux and Windows can't read it.
It seems like the controller is not completely dead (it does identify itself).

Is there any hope of recovering the data on the drive using soft methods (without voiding the warranty)?

There is nothing essential there (I do keep several backups of the really important stuff), but it would be nice to get the other stuff back nonetheless (savegames mostly, no big deal but kind of a pain), and I figure once I RMA it, it will be gone forever.

Hotplugging it (via external enclosure) yields the following dmesg output:

`[40444.428018] usb 3-6.4: new high-speed USB device number 68 using xhci_hcd
[40444.516820] usb 3-6.4: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338
[40444.516823] usb 3-6.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[40444.516825] usb 3-6.4: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge
[40444.516827] usb 3-6.4: Manufacturer: JMicron
[40444.516828] usb 3-6.4: SerialNumber: 143796402260
[40444.517567] usb-storage 3-6.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[40444.518482] scsi host35: usb-storage 3-6.4:1.0
[40445.516659] scsi 35:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  SDSSDHII240G          PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[40445.517028] sd 35:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[40445.517170] sd 35:0:0:0: [sdd] 468862128 512-byte logical blocks: (240 GB/224 GiB)
[40445.517424] sd 35:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[40445.517425] sd 35:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[40445.517672] sd 35:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[40445.517675] sd 35:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[40475.948484] usb 3-6.4: USB disconnect, device number 68
[40475.956035] sd 35:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[40475.956038] sd 35:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[40475.956040] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 0
[40475.956042] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[40475.956096] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[40475.956105] Dev sdd: unable to read RDB block 0
[40475.956117]  sdd: unable to read partition table
[40475.956251] sd 35:0:0:0: [sdd] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[40475.956253] sd 35:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense not available.
[40475.956296] sd 35:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[40476.196054] usb 3-6.4: new high-speed USB device number 69 using xhci_hcd
[40476.285057] usb 3-6.4: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338
[40476.285060] usb 3-6.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[40476.285061] usb 3-6.4: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge
[40476.285062] usb 3-6.4: Manufacturer: JMicron
[40476.285063] usb 3-6.4: SerialNumber: 143796402260
[40476.285845] usb-storage 3-6.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[40476.285937] scsi host36: usb-storage 3-6.4:1.0
[40485.921594] usb 3-6.4: USB disconnect, device number 69`

Comment: I have a few dead-ish SSDs.  I put them in a air tight bag and froze it, and it reads maybe 20% of the time, then blue screen in Windows.  As soon as  I was able to read it, i took out all the data and RMA'd it.  As for recovery, I opened up the SSD casing but not much I could do...